# React Native - Send the id of the item selected in the flatlist to the new screen

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-flatlist, react-native-navigation

I'm new to React Native. I'm adding the data from the API in the flatlist. How can I send the selected item id to the new screen? Here are my home screen codes:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useThemedValues } from '../Theming';
import getStyles from "./Styles/HomeScreenStyles";
import Axios from '../../API/AxiosConfig'
import { FlatList } from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { texts, useLocalization } from "../Localization";


const HomeScreen = (props) => {

    const { styles, colors } = useThemedValues(getStyles);
    const loc = useLocalization();

    const [episodeList, setEpisodeList] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        Axios.get('episode')
            .then(response => {
                let episodes = response.data.results
                setEpisodeList(episodes)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            })
    }, [])

    const _renderEpisodesItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={({ item }) => {
                props.navigation.navigate("episode-detail-screen", {
                    dummy1: 1,
                });
            }}>
                <View style={styles.episodeButton}>
                    <Text style={styles.episodeText}>
                        {loc.t(texts.season)}{item.episode.slice(1, 3)} - {loc.t(texts.episode)}{item.episode.slice(4, 6)}
                    </Text>
                    <Text style={styles.episodeNameText} numberOfLines={1}>{item.name}</Text>
                </View>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        )
    } 
    
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>                
            <FlatList
                data={episodeList}
                renderItem={_renderEpisodesItem}
                keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                style={styles.flatListContainer}
            />
        </View>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

My aim is to display the information of the selected section on the newly opened page.

Answer (score 2):

You can send your prop like so:

```
const _renderEpisodesItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
            props.navigation.navigate("episode-detail-screen", {
                episodeId: item.id,
            });
        }}>
            //...
        </TouchableOpacity>
    )
}
```

And then in your `EpisodeScreen` you can pick that like:

```
const {episodeId} = props.route.params
```

If you using reactnavigation, you cant read this https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params/

Comment: When I try that it giving an error like so: 
Uncaught Error 
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'item.id')

Comment: Oh, my bad. The onPress shouldn't have `{item}` inside. I have edit my ans, please check.

Comment: You're wellcome, btw can you upvote the my ans =))

Comment: I need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote:)